# Why is my slice function not working in C?

Tags: arrays, c, string, slice

Recently I tried to make a slice function using C, and it is not working as I intend it to so I want to know why it is not working. I want the function only to print the specified section of the string (slicing of string).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void slice(char s[], int start, int end);

void slice(char s[], int start, int end);
int main(){
    char s[500];
    printf("enter the full sentence/word \n");
    fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);
    int start, end;
    printf("enter the start of slicing ");
    scanf("%d", start);
    
    printf("enter the end of slicing ");
    scanf("%d", end);
    slice(s, start, end);


}

void slice(char s[], int start, int end){
   
    for(int i= start; i <= end; i++){
       
        printf("%c", s[i]);
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: This question was (also) asked a few hours ago and deleted ([SO 7402-8983](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74028983)).  You don't seem to have learned anything from the information you were given previously — your code still has the same mistakes (including declaring `slice()` twice, and typos in the calls to `scanf()`, and not ensuring that there's a newline at the end of the output, etc.)

Comment: After correcting the calls to `scanf()`, you should validate that `fgets()` and `scanf()` succeeded.  You should validate that the values in `start` and `end` are non-negative integers less than the length of the data that was entered via `fgets()` before trying to use those values.

Comment: Note that you can reduce the body of `slice()` to: `assert(start >= 0 && end >= start && end <= strlen(s)); printf("%.*s\n", end - start, s);`.

Answer (score 2):

This `scanf("%d", start);` is wrong. You need to write to the address of the variable with `&start`. Same goes for `scanf("%d", end);`.

More specifically, your program invokes [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as you are trying to access memory you do not own.